# Mac OS X Lion boots very slowly takes 2 minutes to start

Tags: macos

Leopard was good used to start in second but Lion is taking too much time to start it takes 2-3 minutes to start.

Is it problem with my MBP or anyone experience this before? Please guide help.

Comment: What kind of MacBook Pro do you have? What hard drive are you running? If you have a the first gen 2006 Core Duo MacBook Pro with a slower 5400RPM drive that might be a normal boot time.

Comment: This is not really the information we need. Can you post a kernel.log on pastebin and link it here?

Answer (score 3):

Try a...

### [PRAM Reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379)

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Press and hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys. You must press this key combination before the gray screen appears.
3. Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
4. Release the keys.

Why could this help? ->
Information stored in PRAM includes the *startup volume choice*.

Comment: Performing an SMC reset for a slow booting mac is probably not the best first choice. According to http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964 slow booting is not a common symptom that would require performing a SMC reset?

Comment: @MrDaniel Yes. Probably only resetting the PRAM will help here. I added the SMC reset, because I usually reset both at once when I troubleshoot.

Comment: After a PRAM reset, you should be sure to reselect the startup disk (see @MrDaniel's answer), since that's one of the things stored in the PRAM.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've never done that before. I guess this does not matter for single-boot?

Comment: @gentmatt it's not really necessary, but it will actually speed the boot process (slightly) because the firmware doesn't have to think as much about what to boot from.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the correct startup disk is selected in System Preferences under "Startup Disk". Sometimes your mac might forget which drive it needs to boot from, which may cause it to spend extra time searching for a boot drive at start up.

### [Change your startup disk: Make sure your Lion volume is selected](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mchlp1034.html)

1. Go to *Apple menu > System Preferences*, and then click Startup Disk.
2. Unlock the Startup Disk preferences:
   If necessary, click the lock icon and type the name and password for an administrator.
3. Click the icon of the disk where Lion is installed and restart.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the EFI takes that long to check for bootable disks. If it really takes ages, it's most likely caused by broken storage devices. And if it's this kind of problem, manually selecting the startup disk won't change anything. EFI will still try to enumerate them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like this is a common problem for a few users as referenced here [Lion slow to boot?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1194587&page=2)

It might be caused as a result of upgrading from older versions of Mac OS X to Lion. Their fix was to perform a "clean install of Lion"